# No body present upon receipt with https POST with body using nodejs client and golang server

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, https

I am attempting to send a rest request over https using the following

```
// Construct the POST auth body and options
    let postData = JSON.stringify({
      username: this.state.username,
      password: this.state.password
    });

    console.log(postData);

    var options = {
      host: this.state.peerAddress,
      port: this.state.port,
      path: "/api/" + this.state.channelName + "/user-authorisation",
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Content-Length": postData.length
      }
    };

    console.log(options);

    var postRequest = https.request(options, function(res) {
      console.log("\nstatus code: ", res.statusCode);
      res.setEncoding("utf8");
      res.on("data", function(data) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(data));
      });
    });

    e.preventDefault();

    // post the data
    postRequest.write(postData);
    postRequest.end();
```

The request is sent to the server but there is no body present. I have tested this by sending the same request over postman and it works fine. I am sending the request on Chrome if that makes any difference? I get the following errors on the console but these happen after the request has been sent I believe so that are not really an issue at this point.

```
request.js:149 OPTIONS https://<<address>>:<<port>><<path>> net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
localhost/:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Cheers

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. I used the axios module and it worked great. But I would still like to figure out what I was doing wrong. My code looks exactly the same as yours. I'm pulling my hair out over here.